# Getting name of IEnumerable method

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I have a method that takes a non-generic IEnumerable as a parameter, creates an Enumerator out of it, and iterates over it.

```cs
void Do(IEnumerable something)
{
    foreach(var item in something)
    {
        Foobar(item);
    }
}

void OtherMethod()
{
    Do(MyEnumerable())
}

IEnumerable MyEnumerable()
{
    // ...
}
```

Now, I have a need for the callee to be able to identify what IEnumerable was passed into the method via a string. I could very well use a second parameter, for the caller to specify a name, but I noticed that the `ToString` method for the IEnumerable parameter looks something like this:

```
MyProject.Foo.Bar.MyClass+<MyEnumerable>d__2
```

As you can see, and maybe as one would expect, it's the name of the type that was generated to manage the state of that IEnumerable. Notebly, it includes the exact information I want though, the string "MyEnumerable". This piqued my curiosity. Is it possible to get that information from the IEnumerable parameter somehow? *Without* parsing the type name?

If I call `something.GetType().Name`, I get `"<MyEnumerable>d__2"`, which is just a few characters shy of getting "MyEnumerable" with minimal overhead. I couldn't find the exact string I want anywhere in the IEnumerable's type, but I'm curious if I might've missed something. Does anyone know if it's possible to get just the name without any additional parsing?

To be clear, I realize it's kind of silly to do this, and it's much easier and more efficient to simply pass a string as a second parameter. I'm mostly just curious. Well, and if a method did exist, my code would be cleaner^^

Comment: That's *only* going to happen if the `IEnumerable` is generated by an iterator block. It's just the type generated by the compiler - there isn't any special way to get it because it's an implementation detail. If you *really* want to get the name, then you'll need to parse it out of that - but the format isn't guaranteed to stay the same across compiler versions...

Comment: This is an odd thing to want to do in the first place. What happens if that method gets renamed? Which version of .NET are you using? You could potentially use the new `CallerArgumentExpression` if you happen to be using .NET 6, but even that is still weird. This sounds somewhat like an XY problem.

Comment: @DavidG Yea, it is odd, but there is a reason for it^^ `CallerArgumentExpression` looks pretty interesting, but I'm not on .NET 6 yet. I might try what the output would be with it some time. Thanks for the suggestion. Also thanks @JonSkeet. I guess it's how I thought.

Comment: If you want to know what is being enumerated (rather than the class that produced the enumerator), then how about `void Do<T>(IEnumerable<T> something)`? Let the compiler do the work for you. (Requires the type be known at compile time.)

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks for the suggestion, but I actually want the name of the method that represents the IEnumerable.